# Best way to map a generated list to a task in celery

Tags: celery, celery-task, celeryd

I am looking for some advice as to the best way to map a list generated from a task to another task in celery.

Let's say I have a task called `parse`, which parses a PDF document and outputs a list of pages. Each page then needs to be individually passed to another task called `feed`. This all needs to go inside a task called `process`

So, one way I could do that is this:

```
@celery.task
def process:
    pages = parse.s(path_to_pdf).get()

    feed.map(pages)
```

Of course, that is not a good idea because I am calling `get()` inside a task.

Additionally this is inefficient, since my `parse` task is wrapped around a generator function and is able to yield pages, which means that *it should be possible to queue the first page for feeding before the last page has been yielded by the parser*.

Another possibility is to do this:

```
@celery.task
def process:
    for page in parse.s(path_to_pdf).get():
        feed.delay(page)
```

That example still involves calling `get()` inside a task though. Additionally, this example is an oversimplification and I really need to do some things after all pages have been fed (i.e. in a `chord`).

I am looking for the most optimal way to do this in celery. I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably far too late to be of use to you, but you probably want to use a task chain:

```
@celery.task
def process():
    return chain(parse.s(), feed_map.s())

@celery.task
def feed_map(pages):
    return feed.map(pages)
```

if you have some final task, say `final`, you could do this:

```
@celery.task
def feed_map(pages):
    return chord(feed.map.s(page) for page in pages, final.s)
```

Comment: Actually, that is how I ended up doing it and is still in use that way to this day. It's never too late to provide a good answer, which will hopefully help others. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers @chaimp, I just came across it while looking for an answer to a different question, and had only had to solve this problem myself recently ;)

Comment: I believe the final return should be `return chord(feed.s(page) for page in pages, final.s)`