# Celery chain results from task to map to another

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery application

```
@task
def step_one(items):
    items.sort()
    for i in range(len(items), 100):
        yield items[i:i + 100]

@task
def step_two(batch):
    for item in batch:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.chain(step_one.s([i for i in range 100000]), step_two.map().s()).delay()
```

This does not work because step_two is expecting an iterator, but I want it to take the results from the previous step, what is the correct way to go about this? It would also be nice if tasks could start at the `yield` rather than after the whole list is sorted and chunked.

I have seen this question [Best way to map a generated list to a task in celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291742/best-way-to-map-a-generated-list-to-a-task-in-celery) but I feel that it should not be necessary to create an intermediate step to map the results to another task. Additionally, calling `step_two.map.s()` gives me an error `function object has no attribute s`

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I think this issue thread will be inciteful https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3401