# Feeding the result of a task into a map in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I feel like this is quite a simple use case but not one that I have had success solving from the documentation.

Here is a contrived version of my problem:

I have a task that take a single parameter and returns a list. I want to apply another task to each element in the list. I then (depending on circumstance) may want to continue processing with other tasks.

```
chain(
    my.tasks.divide.s(data),
    my.tasks.conquer.map(),
    ).apply_async().get()
```

or

```
chain(
    my.tasks.divide.s(data),
    my.tasks.conquer.map(),
    my.tasks.unite.s(),
    my.tasks.rule.s(),
    ).apply_async().get()
```

Map doesn't work that way, but I feel like it should! All I want is to chain from a single param to a list and then back.. Surely this is not difficult to do properly?

The 'solutions' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291742/best-way-to-map-a-generated-list-to-a-task-in-celery) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7ucu7b/celery_cant_chain_signature_to_map/) seem over complicated and I can't believe are the best practice.

[The documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) on chords, maps, and chains doesn't help with this particular case.

**EDIT: What I have so far.** The problem here is that I have to call `.apply_async().get()` twice to get the actual result, as the intermediary step returns a chord not the actual result:

```
@app.task()
def divide(item):
    return [x for x in item]

@app.task()
def conquer(item):
    return item.upper()

@app.task()
def rule(items):
    return "".join(items)

@app.task()
def conquer_group(items):
    return group([conquer.s(x) for x in items])

@app.task()
def rule_group(items):
    return chord([conquer.s(x) for x in items], rule.s())

def main():
    print chain(
        divide.s("foobarbaz"),
        rule_group.s(),
        ).apply_async().get().apply_async().get()
```

Comment: Have you tried to [composite your functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739290/composing-functions-in-python)?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `map()` needs an iterable to be instantiated.
That's why one can do `(sample.map(range(100)) | another_task.s()).apply_async()` but not instantiate a `map()` signature that accepts the result of the last task in the chain.
I think the simples way to do this is to instantiate the `map()` signature within a task.

```
@app.task()
def divide(item):
    return [x for x in item]

@app.task()
def conquer(item):
    return item.upper()

@app.task()
def process(items):
    return conquer.map(items)

def run():
    (divide.s("foobar") | process.s()).apply_async()
```